# ¿Cómo puedo trazar una línea horizontal (media de valores) en plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter, plotly

Aprendiendo Plotly. Disponemos del siguiente DataFrame

```
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
start = "2016-1-4"
end = "2020-10-19"
iberdrola = pdr.DataReader("IBE.MC", "yahoo", start, end)
iberdrola = iberdrola[["Close"]]
iberdrola[:3]
```

Utilizando matplotlib, repesento la  gráfica de la evolución en el tiempo de la variable y una recta horizontal representando el valor medio de la cotización.

```
# Import Matplotlib's `pyplot` module as `plt`
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot') 
%matplotlib inline

""" Figure 32 """
# Creating a figure, setting its size and plotting close prices on it
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(iberdrola, color='purple')

# Customizing the axes
plt.xticks(rotation=45, color='teal', size=12)
plt.yticks(rotation=45, color='teal', size=12)

# Setting axes labels
plt.xlabel('Fechas', {'color': 'orange', 'fontsize':15})
plt.ylabel('Precios', {'color': 'orange', 'fontsize':15})

# Importing NumPy library
import numpy as np

# Calculating the mean value of close prices
mean_price = np.mean(iberdrola["Close"])

# Plotting the horizontal line along with the close prices
plt.axhline(mean_price, color='r', linestyle='dashed')

# Importing DateTime from DateTime library
from datetime import datetime

# Plotting text on date 2014-1-7 and price 120
plt.text(datetime(2016,5,7), 8, 'Precio medio', size=15, color='r') # coordenadas x e y, texto,size y color

plt.show()
```

Deseo hacer lo mismo utilizando plotly. Consigo representar la gráfica de la siguiente manera.

```
# Usando plotly.express
import plotly.express as px

# Precio medio de las cotizaciones
mean_price = np.mean(iberdrola["Close"])

df = iberdrola.reset_index()
fig = px.line(df, x='Date', y="Close")
fig.show()
```

En este punto me he quedado bloqueado y no he sido capaz de representar en la misma gráfica la línea horizontal y el texto. Agradeceré ayuda para superar este paso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pintar una línea se hace llamando a `fig.add_shape()` y especificando los parámetros apropiados. El texto se añade con `fig.add_annotation()`.

La parte más "difícil" aquí es las coordenadas x0 y x1 de inicio y fin de línea, o la coordenada x del texto, ya que estas coordenadas son fechas. No obstante se resuelve de forma simple si las sacamos del propio dataframe:

```
df = iberdrola.reset_index()
x0 = df["Date"].iloc[0]            # La primera
x1 = df["Date"].iloc[-1]           # La última
xm = df["Date"].iloc[len(df)//2]   # La del medio
```

Ahora pintamos la gráfica y la línea encima, y el texto 10 píxeles por encima de la línea:

```
mean_price = np.mean(iberdrola["Close"])

fig = px.line(df, x="Date", y="Close")

fig.add_shape(type="line",
    x0=x0, y0=mean_price, x1=x1, y1=mean_price,
    line=dict(color="Red",width=3)
 )

fig.add_annotation(x=xm, y=mean_price,
            text='Precio medio',
            showarrow=False,
            yshift=10)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]